# transparently forwarding firstdomain.com to seconddomain.com

Tags: url, dns, forward

I need to add an entry to DNS Server so when in clients people type **firstdomain.com** they actually browse **seconddomain.com** but they don't see the **seconddomain.com** url

What shall I add to DNS?

Answer (score 0):

Just make them point to the same IP. If both domains refer to the same IP they will access the same resources.

Comment: seconddomain.com is not mine (in it's dns table there is no record for firstdomain.com)

Comment: @AVEbrahimi so you want to have a domain you own (firstdomain) to point to service you don't own. Like having mygoogle.com to point to google.com?